# Crear páginas desde formulario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Quiero que un usuario, al llenar un formulario que solo tenga los campos de título y texto se genere una página adicional que herede estos campos. Y que desde un usuario como el Administrador se pueda editar.
¿Podrías darme alguna idea de cómo poder hacer esto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En esta pagina se contestan dudas puntuales.. vos estas pidiendo opiniones sobre como hacer algo, que podria tener multiples formas de hacerse...

Comment: @zamuken, te fijaste en la documentacion de React, los componentes input  https://es.react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input